# Using angular2-sails module for realtime communication using sockets

Tags: sockets, sails.js, angular5

I would like to use sails.io.js with angular5, so I used angular2-sails module. I managed to connect angular to sails but I didn't manage to retrieve the events from sails.js, for example when a new document is created in database. Is there something to configure sails side ? I used `this.sailsService.on("user").subscribe(data => console.log("event on user"))`. The get and post methods are perfectly working. Sails side I put

```
ioclient:  require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337'),
io: require('sails.io.js'),
```

In config/http.js, instead of

```
var io = require('sails.io.js')( require('socket.io-client') );
```

because else sails cannot load

I didn't write anything in config/socket.js

Answer (score 0):

angular2-sails module is deprecated so I used the io variable from sails.io.js using a service :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
    // return the global native browser window object
    return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    get ioSails(): any {
        return _window().io;
    }
}
```